# Switch between dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies

I have a code which solves differential equations by means of the finite element method. To that end, I use Eigen so I don't have to implement matrices by myself. Now, in the future, I would like to try the same code with another library, like Armadillo. I would like to be able to switch easily between the libraries.

I am new to this, and my question is basically if the following is good practice. In an attempt to make my code work for any matrix library, I define the types `DataType` and `MatrixImplementation` in a header. The latter is the one which should determine whether to use one library or the other.

```
// data type
using DataType = double;

// matrix implementation
template <typename TYPE = DataType, size_t ROWS = 1, size_t COLS = 1>
using MatrixImplementation = Eigen::Matrix<DataType, ROWS, COLS>;
```

I can then check whether or not Eigen is used like this:

```
// check which matrix implementation
constexpr static bool is_eigen = std::is_same<MatrixImplementation<DataType, 1, 1>,Eigen::Matrix<DataType, 1, 1>>::value;
```

I can now define the `IndexType` (typically `size_t` or `unsigned int`) to access the elements of a vector or matrix as follows:

```
// index type
using IndexType = std::conditional_t<is_eigen, Eigen::Index,
                  std::conditional_t<is_armadillo, ..., 
                  std::conditional_t<is_***, ..., 
                  ...>;
```

Likewise, I can define the `Matrix` type as follows:

```
// matrix type
template <size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
using Matrix = std::conditional_t<is_eigen, Eigen::Matrix<DataType, ROWS, COLS>, ...>;
```

and so on. Furthermore, I would have to define the operations on the matrices (only those I need), for instance the norm:

```
template <class Matrix>
constexpr auto norm(const Matrix& m)
{
    if constexpr (is_eigen)
        return m.norm();
    else if constexpr (is_armadillo)
        return ...;
    else
        return 0.0;
}
```

I would then calculate the norm as follows:

```
Matrix<3,3> my_matrix;
auto norm_matrix = norm(my_matrix);
```

Is this the way to go? Or is there a better alternative, maybe some fancy design pattern I should consider?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @MaxLanghof's comment:

> How would you implement is_armadillo when you might only use Eigen at
>   some point? Is your plan to always include all the libraries?

I now let CMake write which matrix library to use into a `config.h` file:

```
#define MATRIX_LIBRARY EIGEN // this value is written by cmake
#define EIGEN 1
#define ARMADILLO 2
```

Now, I can determine if the code is going to use Eigen or Armadillo as follows:

```
#if MATRIX_LIBRARY == EIGEN
constexpr static bool is_eigen = true;
#else
constexpr static bool is_eigen = false;
#endif
#if MATRIX_LIBRARY == ARMADILLO
constexpr static bool is_armadillo = true;
#else
constexpr static bool is_armadillo = false;
#endif
```

Comment: How would you implement `is_armadillo` when you might only use `Eigen` at some point? Is your plan to always include _all_ the libraries?

Comment: In any case, both `Eigen` and `armadillo` are large complex libraries with non-trivial interfaces (same for presumably any other notable C++ matrix library). The core matrix types might have similar enough interfaces to more or less swap them out, but (as you already noticed with `norm`), the other functionality will differ quite a bit. And the difference will probably be more than superficial - maybe one library does an SVD in-place, the other one doesn't. You'd have to sensibly wrap all such functionality yourself. That's no small task and I'm not sure if it's feasible for a larger project.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Good point... It would be stupid to include Armadillo if I want to use Eigen... and then I would not be able to implement is_armadillo... unless I hardcode it, or let cmake generate that variable for me in function of which library is available.

Comment: You probably want to have a look into preprocessor flags (you will have to wrap the definition of `MatrixImplementation` with some `#ifdef`). Then you can set desired flags through the CMake configuration of your project like `-DMYPROJECT_MATRIX_LIB=eigen/armadillo/adhoc`. If you put `#ifdefs` around key definitions and dependencies - you will get the modular behavior. It is a pain in the neck to support this though...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with either of those libraries, but they probably don't implement a common interface. Another approach would be to write a wrapper class that is simply a pass-through to the methods you use in Eigen, but have that implement an interface. Then if you try a new library, write a new wrapper class that implements the same interface. Then you can pick which wrapper to instantiate, and there rest of your code remains untouched.

If you're not familiar with interfaces in C++ -- it's just a virtual base class. You can do a google of "C++ Interface" and get some good writeups.

That's how I would do it.

Comment: But then every call to norm or whatever function would have an indirection if I understand what you mean. And I'd prefer not to have that. In FEM, you can have millions of elements, and I need it to go really fast.

Comment: The interface of most matrix libraries is huge, and in many cases not even compatible on a syntactical level. Wrapping that would be a little more than "a virtual base class". And at least `Eigen` is massively templated, which doesn't mix well with virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Eigen` and `armadillo` are large complex libraries with non-trivial interfaces (same for presumably any other notable C++ matrix library). Each one presumably has its own pitfalls and idiosyncrasies, and beyond basic syntax they will most certainly have plenty of incompatibilities.

So before delving into the specifics of how to do this, I would first take a deep look at whether this is feasible in the first place.

- Do you want to write a few hundred lines of code that mainly does vanilla matrix handling (say, multiplication) which should work more or less the same in any C++ matrix library? Sounds doable.
- Are you planning this project to have thousands of lines of code that deeply interface with specialized matrix functionality (slicing? decompositions? reordering? you will probably want sparse matrices/algorithms?)? Do all those features even exist in each library? Do they use even remotely the same data structures? Does the syntax vary wildly? Do functions take completely different argument? I foresee a painful future for you in this case.

I would first of all recommend keeping your set of supported libraries closed. Define which libraries you want to support as early as possible. Then iterate on conceptual pieces of your solver algorithms and verify that everything you need is present in all the libraries. If you want your code to work with all of them, you have to develop against all of them. You can initially do this using preprocessor switches like

```
#ifdef USE_EIGEN
  // Do the matrix decomposition in one way.
#else
  // Do the matrix decomposition in some other way.
#endif
```

and then refactor these blocks into (essentially) wrapper functions or classes as you go.

It would also pay to be familiar with the different libraries ahead of time (ties in with everything above). You don't want to find out halfway through the project that library `X` has sparse matrices but no meaningful algorithms to actually operate on them!

The code snippets you show look mostly reasonable, except you will likely have to substitute some parts for preprocessor flags. But compared to the challenges you will most likely face (and given that you seem comfortable with type aliases and templates in general) I don't think these things are what you should worry about for now...

Comment: I need very few things for dense matrices (determinant, transpose, initialization, ..., basic stuff). For sparse matrices, just write and invoke a solver. I think I won't have to implement too much. I thought you were going to propose an entire different way of doing this. It seems I'm not headed the wrong direction then...